# When I add Anotation to the ggplot in a 'kaggle's notebook' I get a huge whitespace above graph, how can I fix that

Tags: r, kaggle

I have a problem with a kernel I ran in kaggle,A huge white spaces occurs above the plots I plotted using `ggplot`. I suspect that is because I added annotations to the plots.

I did not get this problem when i ran this in R-studio ,probably i am guessing this issue occurs in notebook.I am keen to know what caused this and how i can resolve this issue ?

Note:earlier I added the link to my kernel in this post, post editing this question the link is not getting visible,hence I removed reference to the kernel link.

The code that caused the issue,

```
 #City pickup point subset
city_p <- filter(uber,Pickup.point=='City')
#add anotations
my_text_city <- "Concern Area"
my_grob_city = grid.text(my_text_city, x=.32,  y=.91, gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=7, fontface="bold",alpha=0.7))
#plot
(city_hourly_alldays <- ggplot(city_p,aes(x=factor(request_hour),fill=Status))+geom_bar(position = 'dodge')+facet_wrap(~request_date,nrow=5)+annotation_custom(my_grob_city))
```

Comment: You expect a lot from _StackOverflow_ users to read such a big amount of code. Better isolate your problem and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sure,I have now added the code, can you check plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "empty space" is actually your grid.text being drawn: by default, when you create a grid.text, even if you assign it to a variable like you are, it is still drawn. This is why you have just the text "Concern Area" in the middle of nowhere.

You can get rid of it by adding the argument `draw = F` to your initial grid.text call.

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
# City pickup point subset
city_p <- filter(uber,Pickup.point=='City')

# Create annotations object
my_text_city <- "Concern Area"
my_grob_city <- grid.text(my_text_city, x=.32,  y=.91,
    gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=7, fontface="bold",alpha=0.7), 
    draw = F)

# Plot
ggplot(city_p,aes(x=factor(request_hour), fill=Status))+
    geom_bar(position = 'dodge')+
    facet_wrap(~request_date, nrow =5)+
    annotation_custom(my_grob_city)
```

I've [created a fork of your notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/u-between-11july-to-15july/) to show that it's not just something funky up with Jupyter.

Hope that helps! :)